# How to send and receive data between two Vue roots?

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

*app.html*

```
<script defer src='app.js'></script>
<script defer src='plugin.js'></script>

<div id='app'></div>
<div id='plugin'></div>
```

*app.js*

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        hi:'hi'
    }
})

const app = new.Vue({
    el:'#app',
    store
})
```

*plugin.js*

```
const plugin = new.Vue({
   mounted(){
       console.log('How can I get hi in store?')
   }
})
```

I want to use Vuex to retrieve data from Vue instances loaded from different files. I have to use this method because the plugins are different for each page and they load dynamically.

But rootState doesn't seem to be able to get app's state, because the root is different. Is there a way to access the data using windows, mixins or some other global object or method?

Comment: Are those two Vue instances on the same page? See also https://forum.vuejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-make-multiple-vue-instances-to-listen-the-same-vuex-store/35190

Comment: In suggested, he used the same store. However, in my case it doesn't use the same store because it is loaded from another script. If so, do I have to use localStorage as suggested?

Comment: If you want to talk from two separate files on the same domain, you could use the localStorage/sessionStorage/indexedDB to communicate with each other. On a website, you usually can only access the data of this exact page, not of any other page on the same domain. So, if this Vue instance is loaded on another HTML page, then you don't have access to anything on that page (including Vuex store).

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'shared state' you can use localStorage, sure, but your question asks more about 'passing' data. In this case you can use an event emitter and listener. Since window has an [Event Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) you can do it like this:

```
// rootA - emitter
{
  methods: {
    emitDataToComponentB (a, b, c) {
       const event = new CustomEvent('someEvent', { ...arguments })
       window.dispatchEvent(event)
    }
  }
}

// rootB - listener
{
  created () {
    this.listen()
  },

  methods: {
    listen () {
      window.addEventListener('someEvent', (args) => {
        console.log('@someEvent', args)
    }
  }
}
```

note: Only code required to meet the need shown. You'd want to make sure you detach any listeners at an appropriate time (eg `rootB.beforeDestroy()`)